# Statistical analysis of Reproductive toxicity study

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

## **Context:**

The design and results of Pfizer’s nonclinical developmental and reproductive toxicity (DART) study were used to support initiation of a clinical trial in pregnant women with BNT162b2, as well as vaccination of women in real life.

The DART study was based on 44 female rats in the treatment group (receiving BNT162b2) and 44 female rats in the control group (receiving saline solution).

> *Overview of the study design. Female rats were administered four intramuscular injections (2 prior to cohabitation with the males and 2 during gestation) of saline (control) or BNT162b2 (44/group). .... Approximately half the rats (n = 22/group) underwent cesarean section on gestation day (GD) 21. The remaining rats (n = 22/group) were allowed to deliver naturally*

Link: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8163337/

## **Findings. In the cesarean group (n=22/group), there were three findings of interest:**

(A)
*"Although the mean percentage pre-implantation loss (difference between number of corpora lutea [CL] and implantation sites divided by CL) was statistically (p < 0.05) higher in the BNT162b2 group (9.77 % compared with 4.09 % in the control group), the value was within the historical control (HC) data range (1.4–16.2 %)"*

(B)
*"Two fetuses in the BNT162b2 group were noted with external observations (1 fetus with gastroschisis and 1 fetus with small mouth and agnathia). The fetus with agnathia and a small mouth had associated skeletal malformations of short and fused mandibles. These external malformations are normal background findings in this strain (are within HC incidence)"*

(C)
*"The visceral malformation of right sided aortic arch was seen in 1 fetus in the BNT162b2 and not in control fetuses. This finding has not been observed in the testing facility HC data with Wistar rats; however, it has been reported in the HC from CRL Den Bosch in the same strain and source (2 fetuses in 2 litters, with a maximum incidence of 0.8 % fetuses/litter), and therefore this single finding was not considered related to BNT162b2 administration."*

## **Questions. I have some questions on statistical analysis please:**

1. How can one determine whether the sample size is large enough for the study to have sufficient power?
2. On finding (A) above. How does one calculate the p-value, based on the data presented in Table 2 of the study?
3. On finding (A), (B) and (C) above. To what extent are the references to the findings being "within historical control (HC) data range" a red herring?

> I notice the historical control data ranges can be very, very wide (in the case of pre-implantation loss it was 1.6% to 16.2%!). Furthermore, is it correct to say “within the historical control range” is not equal to “treatment (BNT162b2) had no effect”, particularly for small samples and rare events?

4. On finding (B) and (C) above. What statistical tests can be applied to determine if the findings are significant?

> It seems to me that the study’s sample size is too small for (B) and (C) to be statistically significant? The study used Fisher’s exact test. Is it fair to say that even if the BNT162b2 group had a rat born with half a heart (or even no head!), and the control group had no defect, the Fisher’s exact test would still give a “not statistically significant” output?

5. Since the study likes to reference the historical control incidence rate, can one “extend" this approach to looking at a collection of malformations in treatment group (n=276 fetsus, in Table 3 of the study) vs. the historical control sample?

> The "analysis" would run as follows:

> There were 3 malformations in the BNT162b2 group (1 gastroschisis, 1 agnathia, 1 malformation of right sided aortic arch), and zero in this study's control group. See Table 3

> Historical control data in the CRL-WI rat from the test facility from years 2013–2019 showed there were a total of 4 fetus with those same malformations (1 gastroschisis, 1 agnathia, 2 malformation of right sided aortic arch). See Table 3.

> How many control rats were studied during the historic control data period of 2013-2019? Simplistically, one could estimated that number to be about 2,400 (based on incidence rate of “Supernumerary lumbar, short” in this study’s control group vs in the CRL-Lyon Historical Control data disclosed in Table 3)

> Applying Fisher's exact test, there is a statistically significant association between treatment (BNT162b2) and a malformation outcome (gastroschisis, agnathia or malformation of right sided aortic arch). P-value is 0.0276.